# Why AJAX POST results in an Undefined array key error?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am trying to pass a text string to a PHP Variable using AJAX, but I keep getting this error when POST fires:

> Warning: Undefined array key "mydata"

the alert fires and displays the value correctly, but then the PHP page displays the mentioned error. What's wrong here?

AJAX:

```
$("#display_tasks").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    var namecut = name.substr(0,name.indexOf(' |'));
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'opentask.php',
         data: {mydata : namecut},
         success:function(data) {
             alert(data);
         }
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$taskname = $_POST['mydata'];
echo $taskname;
```

Comment: Just while debugging, make the data capture SIMPLE and do just `var namecut = 'HELLO';` and see if you get anything back

Comment: thank you for your response. I actually did debug before I posted, the namecut returns the expected value no problem and alerts it fine too, the success alert also display the text properly, but when the PHP fires it causes the error on the php page

Comment: @KenLee the error is gone, but nothing is returned, blank page only. I assume that the post is not reading the value properly? why is that?

Comment: If you send a string to PHP and the PHP returns the CORRECT String to the JS and the `alert(data);` shows the right string. Then the fact you are getting an error from the PHP does not compute

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have other PHP file that I retrieve the text from, but when I try to send the text to the other PHP file, it alerts the value via JS correctly, but PHP fails to echo the value because an error in POST precedes it. this is my view to how things are going. I would be grateful if you could guide me to where I might be wrong here.

Comment: @KenLee I think I am using a very recent PHP version, I tried both of the solutions and it returns the same, just blank page with no error.

Comment: I think there must be something wrong .... Did you show all the related code ? Please show the part / block related to display_tasks id too

Comment: @KenLee this is the related code from the other PHP file and it works fine inside the whole html page:
<?php
            echo '<a id="display_tasks" href="opentask.php">'.$displaytaskrowresult.'</a>';
?>

$displaytaskrowresult contains text like this: "ABCD | Text"

I try to use JQUERY & AJAX to read its value through <a> id="display_tasks" onclick event, then substring the " | Text" part, then pass the "ABCD" value as a string to another PHP file to be assigned in a variable, in order to use it in a MYSQL query later.

Comment: @KenLee maybe the wrong part is passing the opentask.php twice, in 1st PHP href, and in AJAX url?
I want to go to that page and execute its code at the same time, is this wrong?

Comment: Yes, please refer to my suggested answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please **remove** `href="opentask.php"` from the following line (you just need the ajax to call opentask.php) :

```
<a id="display_tasks" href="opentask.php">
```

Secondly , please use `isset` to check the existence of $_POST['mydata'] before assigning it to $taskname

So please use

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-3zlB5s2uwoUzrXK3BT7AX3FyvojsraNFxCc2vC/7pNI="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<?php 
$displaytaskrowresult="ABCD | Text";
echo '<a id="display_tasks">'.$displaytaskrowresult.'</a>'; ?> 

<script>
$("#display_tasks").click(function() {
    var name = $(this).text();
    var namecut = name.substr(0,name.indexOf(' |'));
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'opentask.php',
         data: {mydata : namecut},
         success:function(data) {
             alert(data);
             window.location.href="opentask.php";
         }
    });
});

</script>
```

and

opentask.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);

$taskname = isset($_POST['mydata']) ? $_POST['mydata']: '' ;
echo $taskname;
?>
```

Please visit the following sandbox to see the effect:

http://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/subj/test1.php

**[Additional point]**

If you just want to test POST request to be displayed in the target page, please use a form submission. (because ajax will only return the result back to the calling page in the success block.)

Comment: I understand now where I was wrong, but one last issue, I want the ability to navigate to opentask.php after clicking the <a> href link, now when I remove the href, there's no pages to go (when I click it does nothing), how to overcome this issue?

Comment: You can add `window.location.href="opentask.php";` into the **success** block of ajax (see my revised answer and try the sandbox link too)

Comment: I opened the link and applied the code myself, and both return empty blank page too after successful value in alert.. still the POST is not working. I apologize for burdening you with such inquiry.

Comment: (1) Please note that it is normal if you see "an empty page" because the opentask.php is supposed to return the $_POST["mydata"] only, so if you merely do a page redirection (which will not have a POST), then the opentask.php is an empty page. Actually you should get the page redirected to some other pages such as "welcome.php" containing the text "Welcome", etc. and you will see the difference. (2) The POST is of course working, otherwise you will not see "ABCD" as an alert on return from the ajax

Comment: but why it doesn't echo the variable $taskname?
when I use a code to check if POST is not empy, I echo "failure" in the Else part, and it echoes just fine. if it's successful, why no variable name is displayed?

Comment: Simply because we have the line $taskname = isset($_POST['mydata']) ? $_POST['mydata']: '' ; . If you change to `$taskname = isset($_POST['mydata']) ? $_POST['mydata']: 'DIRECT CALL' ;` , it will show the word "DIRECT CALL" (please click the sandbox link again and see the effect now....)

Comment: no, I mean how could I display the $taskname variable?
after the alert, I want it printed on the page, this line: echo $taskname is not working, I want to show ABCD on page, after alert

Comment: If you just want to test POST request to be displayed in the target page, please use a form submission. (because ajax will only return the result back to the calling page in the success block. It is the purpose of ajax)

Comment: oh, I see!
does this mean if I use my $taskname variable in a MYSQL query, it will be passed without being shown?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Please continue to test and learn in your journey of PHP/MySQL coding. Have a nice day.

Comment: thank you for your enormous help, I am very grateful to you!:)

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$_POST['mydata']` always, not just when receiving AJAX request. And when you are just showing the page, the superglobal array $_POST haven't got an element indexed by 'mydata'. That's why you get the error.

A way to avoid this is to separate AJAX receiving request to another file. This is like is done by several PHP applications.

A simpler way you can use to test is to check $_POST, for example you can do this:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $taskname = $_POST['mydata'];
    echo $taskname;
}
```

That way you only try to use `$_POST['mydata`]` when you are receiving a POST. Also, if element 'mydata' is not present, you will still get an undefined array key error.

Comment: hello, thanks for your response.
I tried that, but it just returns blank white page with no error. this means that the POST is empty, but how come it's empty when AJAX passed the value?

Comment: I tested it and it works. However, the solution from Ken Lee, accepted by you, looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

Replace `var name = $(this).text();`

with `var name= $(this).attr('value');`
or
`document.getElementById('name').value`

name is the text input name
I think this will work and test if it gets by console.log(name) first

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, same error. I think the error is related to POST, the value reads right with .text(), i debugged it and it ran fine.
thanks for your proposed idea

Comment: ok check it with isset method 
if (isset($_POST['mydata'])) {
    $taskname = $_POST['mydata'];
    echo $taskname;
}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).